# TS export declaration vs export list with isolatedModules

Tags: typescript

My `tsconfig.json` has `"isolatedModules": true` (typescript v4.8.4)

In a `hanlder.ts` file, if I do this, then TS warns me about `TS1205: Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.`

```js
// handler.ts

interface Handler {
    handle(): Promise<void>;
}

export {
  Handler // This is not allowed
};
```

but if I use export declaration instead, then it works:

```js
// handler.ts

export interface Handler { // This is fine
    handle(): Promise<void>;
}
```

Does anyone know why these two cases are treated differently by TS?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in this example is setting the isolatedModules flag tells TypeScript to warn you if you write certain code that can’t be correctly interpreted by a single-file transpilation process. read more about it in the [typescript tsconfig documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules)

> import type only imports declarations to be used for type annotations and declarations. It always gets fully erased, so there’s no remnant of it at runtime. Similarly, export type only provides an export that can be used for type contexts, and is also erased from TypeScript’s output.
>
> It’s important to note that classes have a value at runtime and a type
> at design-time, and the use is context-sensitive. When using import
> type to import a class, you can’t do things like extend from it.

You can get out of this problem by defining that it's a type since that will only be relevant under transpile-time as described in [Type only export and imports](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35200) also explained in [TypeScript 3.8 releasenotes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export).

```
interface Handler {
  handle(): Promise<void>;
}

export type { Handler };
```

Comment: Thanks.  So why is the second case ok?  How is it different from the first case?